# asynchronous console output to a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf

i would like to execute an executable file with some parameters.

I would like my WPF application to output the console lines and show it in a textblock asynchronously.

This is what i've done so far:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
System.Diagnostics.Process runantc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
runantc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
runantc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Antcbatchpath;
runantc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

runantc.OutputDataReceived +=new DataReceivedEventHandler(runantc_OutputDataReceived);

runantc.Start();

runantc.BeginOutputReadLine();

runantc.Close(); 

private static void runantc_OutputDataReceived (object sendingProcess, 
DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
 //i am not sure what should be here
}
```

The above code is altered according to msdn's [webpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx)

I have a lot of trouble following their code namely because they need to add in strings or some sort. I am a beginner at events handling and such processes. Please kindly help me, all i need is just to output these lines to a textblock asynchronously.

For example, the console would output:

```
running test...
```

i should see that in textblock:

```
running test...
```

then after a few seconds another line appears:

```
running test...
this is a new line 1
```

and the above should also appear in the textblock after a few seconds:

```
running test...
this is a new line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you want:

```
private static void runantc_OutputDataReceived (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    YourControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { YourControl.Text += outLine.Data; }), null);
}
```

EDIT: Ok it seems I have to explain the code a little bit:

The Dispatcher.BeginInvoke function needs a delegate as callback and an array of parameters.

- Dispatcher.BeginInvoke http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824.aspx
- Delegate (the first parameter of BeginInvoke) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx
- Action (a delegate) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx
- Lambda Expression ( f.e. () => {...} executes the code in { ... }) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
- params keyword http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: try again. i should next time test this in vs... a closing ) was missing for new Action(..)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will appear as you are expecting, but you can get the details from the output text using `DataReceivedEventArgs.Data` property.